# trying to swap links in a linked list, doesnt seem to work

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

```java
 public void question1(int key1,int key2){
    //swapping keys by changing links not data:
    Node temp = Head;
    Node tempStr1 = null;
    Node nextStr1=null,NextStr2=null;
    Node tempstr2 = null;
    while(temp.Next!=null){
        if(temp.Next.data==key1){
            nextStr1=temp.Next.Next;
            tempStr1 = temp.Next;
        }
        if(temp.Next.data==key2){
            NextStr2 = temp.Next.Next;
            tempstr2 = temp.Next;//storing in temp var
        }
        temp=temp.Next;//update
    }
    while(temp.Next!=null){
        if(temp.Next.data==key1){
            temp.Next = tempstr2;
            tempstr2.Next = nextStr1;
        }
        if(temp.Next.data==key2){
            temp.Next = tempStr1;//swap
            tempStr1.Next = NextStr2;
        }
        temp=temp.Next;//update
    }

}
    }
public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        ll.addFirst(1);
        ll.addFirst(2);
        ll.addFirst(3);
        ll.addFirst(4);
        ll.addFirst(5);
        ll.addFirst(6);
        ll.Print();
        ll.question1(3, 2 );
       ll.Print();
```

**i dont seem to understand why is this not doing the trick,
the goal is to swap the two nodes by just changing the links
expected outcome:6 5 4 2 3 1
real outcome:6 5 4 3 2 1**
writing this code for the question:
Swapping Nodes in a Linked ListWehavealinkedlistandtwokeysinit,swapnodesfortwogivenkeys.Nodesshouldbeswappedbychanginglinks.Swappingdataofnodesmaybeexpensiveinmanysituationswhendata contains many fields. It may be assumed that all keys in the linked list are distinct.

Comment: What is the nodes before Node1 & Node2 pointing to after you swapped the nodes?

Comment: @cliff2310 thanks,i noticed that, fixed that from my end i think, the code still doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- The second loop will never iterate, because the first loop will end when `temp.Next` is `null`, and since the second loop will only iterate when this is *not* the case, it is useless. This practically means there will never be a swap.
- Even if you would reset `temp` to `null` just before the second loop starts, it is a pity that you need to iterate the whole list *again*, just to find the same two nodes *again*.
- If in the second loop the first condition is true, then the first `if` block will make that `temp.Next` references the node with key2, but that means that the second `if` condition is also true now, and the change will be reverted again.
- There is no provision where the *head* node would have to be swapped.
- No distinction is made between the case where two *consecutive* nodes need to be swapped (which involves 3 references to be updated) and where the swapped nodes are not each other's neighbor (which involves 4 references to be updated).

I would suggest that you only have one loop, and when you have found both positions, you make the swap immediately.

Also, to involve the head as a potential candidate for a swap, I'd suggest temporarily prepending the list with a dummy node so that the `while` loop can start one step earlier and detect the wanted key also in the head node. After the swap that dummy node should be removed again. This way the final `Head` node could actually be a different one than was originally the case.

Here is the suggested code:

```
    public void question1(int key1, int key2) {
        // Swapping keys by changing links not data:
        addFirst(0); // Prepend list with some dummy value
        Node temp = null; // Used for swapping
        Node before1 = null; // Node that precedes the first match
        Node before2 = Head; // Node that eventually precedes the second match
        
        while (before2.Next != null) {
            if (before2.Next.data == key1 || before2.Next.data == key2) {
                if (before1 == null) { // First match
                    before1 = before2;  // Save that match
                } else { // Second match
                    if (before1.Next == before2) { // Special case
                        before1.Next = before2.Next;
                        before2.Next = before2.Next.Next;
                        before1.Next.Next = before2;
                    } else {
                        temp = before1.Next.Next;
                        before1.Next.Next = before2.Next.Next;
                        before2.Next.Next = temp;
            
                        temp = before1.Next;
                        before1.Next = before2.Next;
                        before2.Next = temp;
                    }
                    break; // All done
                }
            }
            before2 = before2.Next;
        }
        // Remove the dummy Node
        Head = Head.Next;
    }
```